# slow access/reads of linux md raid1 array

Tags: linux, mdadm, raid1, md

I have a Linux md-raid raid1 array (ext4 fs), with 2 3TB disks. The array has been showing significant slowness in access and read times over the last few months. Doing an `ls` on a directory w/ less than 20 records can sometimes take 2-3 minutes to return.

It seems to spend a lot of time with a state of "checking," but even when the state is "clean," access and read times are very slow. I don't find any errors being reported in the system logs. The only thing of note is that the FS has been close to full for a while now. The output of `mdadm -D /dev/md127` shows:

```
/dev/md127:
     Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Jun 20 11:34:21 2019
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 2930132992 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930132992 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Sep 26 13:58:50 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : giles:meta  (local to host giles)
              UUID : 638efea5:1e7b07d2:78fec1dc:d919dccf
            Events : 8359

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this or suggestions on debugging it? I'm in the process of copying the data to a new set of larger drives and it has only copied 301GB in over 48 hours.

Comment: check your kernel log (probably /var/log/kern.log) or run `dmesg -w` - are there lots of read errors?  if so, then one or both of those drives is failing and you're doing exactly the right thing by moving your data to other drives.  I recommend using `rsync` if you're not already using it so that you can restart from where it left off if the copy dies before completion.

Comment: If only one of the drives is failing, you can take advantage of the fact that (with mdadm raid-1) you can use any of the mirror drives independently.  Find out which of the drives is failing (from your kernel log), unmount the md127 array, and mount the one that **isn't** failing (either /dev/sda1 or /dev/sdb1) in read-only mode,  Copying from that should proceed at normal speed.  You will want to do this from a rescue CD/USB, not while the system is running normally.   Alternatively, use ddrescue to make an image copy of just one of the drives.

Comment: If you need to do this while the system is still running normally, you can use `mdadm` to mark one of the drives as faulty.  e.g. `mdadm --set-faulty /dev/md127 /dev/sda1` (**if** sda1 is the faulty drive).  you should then be able to rsync or cp the files at normal speed.  In fact, this is better than unmounting md127 and mounting one of the mirrors by itself.  If you need to add the drive back into the array, you can use `mdadm --re-add /dev/md127 /dev/sda1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. The syslog indeed shows smartctl/smartd reporting a bunch of errors on sdb. I failed the drive (`mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --fail /dev/sdb1`) and removed it from the array (`mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --remove /dev/sdb1`), after which the copy of data to the new array completed in a few hours.

The lesson for me here is that setting mdadm to send email notification of raid issues isn't enough (it promptly sent me an email about the raid status after I manually failed the drive). I need to set some automated reporting from smartd, so I have earlier warning than just wondering what's going on with disk io performance.